# Solr - How to weight field entries of a multivalued field?

Tags: solr, categories, weighted

I store categories in documents which should be weighted in the documents itself, e.g. Restaurant - 0.5 (= 50%), Bar - 0.25, Music - 0.25. Unfortunately I'm new to solr and don't really know to which feature in solr it could belong.

The documents look like this:

```
    <str name="id">C1</str>
    <str name="name">Wine</str>
    <str name="type">Compass</str>
    <str name="geo">51.049842,13.740707</str>
    <double name="radius">5.0</double>
    <arr name="cat">
      <str>Restaurant</str>
      <str>Restaurant</str>
      <str>Bar</str>
      <str>Music</str>
    </arr>
```

How could I query the expected weitght? Is there an other way than store similar entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with Payload feature of Solr/Lucene. [Getting Started with Payloads](http://searchhub.org/2010/04/18/refresh-getting-started-with-payloads/) will give you the general idea. 
Your document with payloads  will look like:

```
<str name="id">C1</str>
<str name="name">Wine</str>
<str name="type">Compass</str>
<str name="geo">51.049842,13.740707</str>
<double name="radius">5.0</double>
<arr name="cat">
  <str>Restaurant|50</str>
  <str>Bar|25</str>
  <str>Music|25</str>
</arr>
```

After you indexed the document you can have a custom score for your document, that can be  based only on payloads or on a combination with lucene default span score.

You can find more examples of payload query usage in [lucene-solr/tests](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/192f43d7b28f9b9d7ef47ebd11138a2071e3d851/lucene/core/src/test/org/apache/lucene/search/payloads).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I already found this feature too, but I don't really understand how to use it. How could I modify the payloads, e.g. if it should be Restaurant - 40, Bar - 35, Music - 25 after an update? How would a query look like?

Comment: You mentioned that you want to store the weights at the index time, if it is the case than payloads are the way to go. Here is a somewhat more detailed, step by step tutorial: http://hnagtech.wordpress.com/2013/04/19/using-payloads-with-solr-4-x/.

Comment: I have to use SolrNet, so I can't use the Java-API of Solr. So I need a tutorial that Shows, how build queries to use payloads etc.

Comment: If you know the term weights at the query time (eX: different weights based on a user profile) then you can use query term boost which comes out of the box(ex: ..?q=cat:restaurant^10 cat:Bar^4 ..). In order to update the payloads weights you can do a partial update on the multivalued field or just reindex the document, exactly as for any other document update.

Comment: I don't know the weights when I am querying. Is there an other way?

Comment: The analyzer/similarity/payload query parsing-building parts can be implemented in Java on the Solr server side as a Solr plugin. Like this you can use SolrNet for the client side.